# V-shape of error function of numerical derivative vs. analytical derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods

I'm given the following function:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{\sin(x)}$$

and I'm supposed to derive the derivative numerically at the point $x=1$ with the following central difference quotient:

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$$

If I define the error between the two terms as the following:

$$E_{f,x}(h) = \left| \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}-f'(x) \right| $$

For h I take the values $10^{-i}$ for $i\in \{1,...,15\}$ and get the following log-scaled graph.

[image: V-shape error]

Can anybody tell me why I get this kind of error plot? Why does the error at one point increase, although I get closer and closer to the actual value of x?

Comment: What is the accuracy of the datatype you are using to represent numbers? Typically floating point numbers are represented to about 7 decimal places, which is about where your graph seems to have its minimum.

Comment: I've used variables of type "double" in Java. I used R for the plotting, but I think R uses double precision floating point numbers as well.

Comment: What you have is normal. In priciple, we should never use a relative step size smaller than the square root of machine accuracy (the smallest $\epsilon$ such that $1+\epsilon \gt 1$) .

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for your answer. Is that the explanation for the v-shape, that the step size become to small for the machine to handle?

Comment: @eager2learn. This is correct ! Can you compute your $\epsilon$ please and report ? I am very concerned by this problem (for 55 years in the area of numerical simulation). Cheers.

Comment: Ok I get this value as my epsilon: 2.220446049250313E-16